# Audio works within Eclipse but not in .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, jar

The following code does work great when run from within eclipse. But when I export it to a .jar file and try running from the jar, the audio plays for half a sec, and its about 3 seconds long.  The sound files are not located in the jar.  I obtain a path using System.getProperties("user.home") + PathToAudioFile;  Here is my current segment of code:

```
public void postFloorLoc(String FloorLoc)
{   String audiopath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/BortechData/audio/";

    txtFloorLocation.setText(FloorLoc);
    //choosing which file to play
    if(FloorLoc.contentEquals("1-FIFO"))
        audiopath = audiopath + "1-fifo.wav";
    if(FloorLoc.contentEquals("10-FIFO"))
        audiopath = audiopath + "10-fifo.wav";
    aufile = new File(audiopath);
    if(FloorLoc.contentEquals("1-FIFO") || FloorLoc.contentEquals("10-FIFO"))
    {   Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Line.Info linfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
                Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(linfo);
                Clip auClip = (Clip)line;
                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(aufile);
                auClip.open(ais);
                auClip.setFramePosition(0);
                auClip.start();
            }
            catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae)
            { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, uae); }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            { System.out.println(ioe); }
            catch(LineUnavailableException lua)
            { System.out.println(lua); }

            }

        }); 
        t.start();

    }
}
```

All other requests for help have about the same thing.  Again this works great within eclipse, but as a jar I only get half of a second of audio out of about 3 seconds.  So, its finding the file and starts to play it but does not play all of it.  What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's buffering the whole clip in Eclipse, but not from the command line. Try increasing the size of the memory allocation pool (-Xmx1024m for a GB) and see if it plays more of it?